# MS Access how to show records where in Field is "XYZ"

Tags: database, microsoft-access, sql

I Have a Query to show me records. I want it to show me all records when in a Field (let's name it Letters), is "XYZ".
The thing is some entries start with XYZ, in some it's somewhere in the middle and in some it's on the end.
I tried to use InStr and Like but they weren't really helpful.

Maybe you have some ideas ?

Comment: The answer exists in [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23272491/how-to-use-like-operator-with-wildcards-in-parameterized-query-in-ms-access).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show data that contains only XYZ:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable 
WHERE myColumn = 'XYZ'
```

To show data that contains XYZ:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable 
WHERE myColumn LIKE '*XYZ*'
```

To show data that start with XYZ:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable 
WHERE myColumn LIKE 'XYZ*'
```

To show data that end with XYZ:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable 
WHERE myColumn LIKE '*XYZ'
```

Comment: Thanks ! 
Works like a charm.

Is it possible to use Like in When statment ?



For example When(Field Like '*XYZ*'= True; Option1;Option2)

Comment: @Jazzyk Please visit the [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour) and [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers) .